# Total sum value out of Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a drugstore chain database. In the script below I'm trying to print out

- store
- category
- sales of particular category in the particular store
- total sales of the particular category in all the stores

My code:

```
SELECT 
    s.store_name AS [Drug Store],
    g.group_name AS [Category],
    SUM(f.quantity) AS [Sales pcs.]
    -- (SELECT SUM(quantity) AS [Total sales] GROUP BY g.group_name)
FROM 
    [dbo].[fct_cheque] AS f
INNER JOIN
    [dim_stores] AS s ON s.store_id = f.store_id
INNER JOIN
    dim_goods AS g ON g.good_id = f.good_id 
WHERE
    date_id BETWEEN '20170601' AND '20170630'
GROUP BY
    s.store_name, g.group_name
```

How to handle the last one?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would go a long way to clarifying your question.

Comment: If `date_id` has a time component then `BETWEEN` is giving wrong results, see https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `SUM()` as an analytic function, for the second sum which is commented out in your question:

```sql
SELECT s.store_name AS [Drug Store],
       g.group_name AS [Category],
       SUM(f.quantity) AS [Sales pcs.],
       SUM(SUM(f.quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY g.group_name) AS [Total sales]
FROM [dbo].[fct_cheque] AS f
INNER JOIN [dim_stores] AS s ON s.store_id = f.store_id
INNER JOIN dim_goods AS g ON g.good_id = f.good_id
WHERE date_id BETWEEN '20170601' AND '20170630'
GROUP BY s.store_name, g.group_name;
```